# Type mismatch: cannot convert from WebElement to List<WebElement>

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, appium

Whenever I am trying to use a list element, this error is showing

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from WebElement to List<WebElement>`

in appium. Please help!

```
List <WebElement>a=driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.EditText"));
```

Comment: use findElements() method when you're trying to find a list of elements or more than one elements. It may be due to this.

Comment: Glad it worked after imorting the library .

Comment: Voting to leave open.  This is a type of question that I would have come to SQA looking for an answer for when I first started with automation.

Answer (score 3):

Just replace the `findElement ()` method with `findElement**s**(plural)`.

Since the `findElement` method always returns a `WebElement` instead of a List of WebElements. The `findElements` method will return the list of webelements, which can be referred by a variable of type `List<Webelement>`.

So the line of code will looks like,..

```
List<WebElement> a=driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText"));
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `findElement` method which will return single element but you are try to save it in the list.

Your code should be

```
 WebElement a=driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.EditText"));
```